# what is the complexity of the code given below?

Tags: python, complexity-theory

**Code:-**

```
def complexity(x):
  total=0
  while(x>0):
    x/=2
    total+=1
  return total
```

Assume the size of x to be n.
So according to me it should be  1 + 5*(log2(n) + 1) + 1.

Give a logical explanation along with the solution.

Comment: What's your opinion?

Comment: See [help/on-topic] point #3.

Comment: please see the edited question .

Comment: If you are interested in the result expressed in the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) then just discard various kinds of constants there and you are done.

Comment: Yes, complexity of the code is `O(log(n))`

Comment: can anyone give some explanation for this part log2(n) + 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial assumption that the Big O is `1 + 5*(log2(n) + 1) + 1` is close but not quite there. When we use Big O notation, we drop all constants i.e. we would drop the `+1`s and the `5*` from the estimation. To fully understand why, you might want to see this question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/justification-for-neglecting-constants-in-big-o

Dropping all constants, the answer would become just **log(n)** (note that all logs are constant factors from each other, so we just say log(n) instead of any specific log. Ex: log2(n) = log10(n) / log10(2).

Comment: Crap, how do I do latex in stackoverflow?

Comment: Hie vedaad 1 + 5*(log2(n) + 1) + 1 is the solution given in the book but no explanation has been given there , could you please explain how did they found the result as mentioned above. Regarding the  Big O notation i am totally clear.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure Big O notation omits constants, both additive and multiplicative (I even checked again on wikipedia), hence the `log(n)`. Although Big O notation is the most common and frequently used complexity analysis among computer scientists, there are many more notations that you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations). Perhaps your book is concerned with one of these other notations? In any case, the Big O still remains `log(n)`